# filtering variables in meteor/blaze template

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

Suppose I have a Meteor template that I want to use inside of other Meteor templates.

```
<template name="helpsout">
  <p><b>{{text}}</b></p>
</template>
```

Suppose I want to call this helper from another template `needshelp` that gets an array of strings `arr` as a helper, and I want to invoke the `helpsout` template on each element of `arr` but modifying it first say by prepending "this needs help: ".  I'd like to write something like this:

```
<template name="needshelp">
    {{#each arr}}
      {{> helpsout text="this needs help: {{this}}"}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

But the `{{this}}` is not interpolated and it ends up setting `text` to the literal `"this needs help: {{this}}"`.

Is there a way to do this without copying the contents of `helpsout` directly into `needshelp`?  (You can imagine that `helpsout` is actually a complex template that's used by several other templates so we wouldn't want to copy it into each of the places it's being used.)  It seems like having subexpressions would do it but AFAIK this isn't currently supported in Meteor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices:

**prefix is common**

If it's a common pattern in your app that `helpsout` should be called with some sort of body text along with some prefix text, I would modify the context of `helpsout` so that it takes a `body` and an optional `prefix` like so:

```html
<template name="needshelp">
  {{#each arr}}
    {{> helpsout prefix="this needs help: " body=this}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.helpsout.helpers({
  text: function() {
    return (this.prefix || '') + this.body;
  }
});
```

**prefix is uncommon**

If you'd prefer to keep your code as it is with no changes to `helpsout` then you can use an additional helper in your `needshelp` template to set the context:

```html
<template name="needshelp">
  {{#each arr}}
    {{> helpsout text=helpText}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.needshelp.helpers({
  helpText: function() {
    return "this needs help: " + this;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, David.  So if I understand correctly it's not possible to do something like the "prefix is uncommon" method but leave all the text (i.e. the prefix) in the template file?  I was hoping not to put the prefix into the helpers for the sake of separation of concerns.

Comment: Unfortunately no - you can't do string interpolation or other arbitrary js code while setting the context.